# Cors filter not working for spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, cors, servlet-filters

I am working on spring boot filters. I have registered the CORS bean as

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean simpleCORSFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        SimpleCORSFilter filter = new SimpleCORSFilter();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");

        config.applyPermitDefaultValues();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        bean.setFilter(filter);
        return bean;
    }
```

I have written a filter class for the same.
Though the class is getting instantiated but the request from UI is failing here.

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            LOGGER.info("start");

                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization,auth-token");
                if(request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name())){
                    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value());
                }else{
                    AuthenticationRequestWrapper requestAuth = new AuthenticationRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
                    filterChain.doFilter(requestAuth, response);
                }
                LOGGER.info("end");
    }
}
```

But still I am getting the following error

```
cors header ‘access-control-allow-origin’ missing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to offcial Spring Boot documentation :

- [**Enabling Cross Origin Requests for a RESTful Web Service**](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

Here's an example of how to configure CORS with annotations and filters :

### Enabling CORS

**Controller method CORS configuration**

So that the RESTful web service will include CORS access control headers in its response, you just have to add a `@CrossOrigin` annotation to the handler method:

```
src/main/java/hello/GreetingController.java
```

---

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
    System.out.println("==== in greeting ====");
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
}
```

**Global CORS configuration**

As an alternative to fine-grained annotation-based configuration, you can also define some global CORS configuration as well. This is similar to using a `Filter` based solution, but can be declared within Spring MVC and combined with fine-grained `@CrossOrigin` configuration. By default all origins and `GET`, `HEAD` and `POST` methods are allowed.

```
src/main/java/hello/GreetingController.java
```

---

```
@GetMapping("/greeting-javaconfig")
public Greeting greetingWithJavaconfig(@RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
    System.out.println("==== in greeting ====");
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
}
```

---

```
src/main/java/hello/Application.java
```

---

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you need bean for that. Also adding `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` just after `@Component` maybe will solve your problem. This will tell spring that this configuration should be with highest precedence. And in order to be consistent use `HttpServletResponse.SC_OK` instead `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value()`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to try using this one https://gist.github.com/keesun/2245179

Works for me, then add it to `WebMvcConfigurer`

```
public class Interceptors implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  private final CorsInterceptor corsInterceptor;

  @Autowired
  public Interceptors(CorsInterceptor corsInterceptor) {
    this.corsInterceptor = corsInterceptor;
  }

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(this.corsInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**");
  }
}
```

I also added `@Configuration` to the `CorsInterceptor` class

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I thought that my spring cors configuration was wrong, but what I realized was that the request must fulfill some requirements:

> the method must be OPTIONS
> the presence of the Origin header
> the presence of the Access-Control-Allow-Methods header

I found that [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/9711#issuecomment-314207691)

Try this:

1-Just add the @CrossOrigin annotation to your controller
2-Send your request with this 2 headers using OPTIONS method:
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Origin:*

You should get your Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Juani